# Reading data from Excel File In java the file path not working the same as it should be

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding, apache-poi

Iam reading from the Excel file by  asking user to browse for the file and select it and here comes the  problem
lets say we have excel file called  abc.xls ( contain arabic Strings )
if the user selected this file by browsing it  all the data extracted from the file 
are like this ??????? 
but if i staticly intatlized the file path with the same path the user selected , in the program before the program starts and neglected the user input  the program is getting correct results 
iam using the apache.poi to extract data from excel file

to sumarize (is the problem is in the File Path  or the Excel library used for extraction)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can connect to your issue really as I have made a few CRON jobs myself lately(strictly numbers and English alphabets).

I see that giving path in a variable (static approach) works fine, 
but now that you say that the file contents are Arabic stuff, so I can say that plz Google and check your UTF-8 setup.

Your file text showing "??????" or any unexpected output simply means you need to check that you have proper requirements for Arabic Unicode whatsoever.

Comment: No issues !Happy coding !